# clicking a button on a password protected website in python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to write a script that pushes a button that looks like this in HTML code:

```
<button type="button" class="button save create">
    <img src="img/tick-circle.png" title="" alt="">
        Create
</button>
```

I read this post: [Python: clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063091/python-clicking-a-button) but I can't figure out how to translate it to my problem because the website I am trying to click a button on does not take me to a new page once the button is clicked. Any suggestions?